# CMake error: common is required but boost was not found

Tags: c++, qt, boost, cmake

I'm trying to compile opencv_2.4.9 with cmake_3.5.0 to run a project in Qt_5.3.2 MinGW and it keeps showing this error:

[Common needed but can't find boost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UOpr.png)

I choose "MinGW Makefiles" as generator and "specify native compilers" in configure window. I defined BOOST_ROOT environmental variable and this is my CmakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)

SET(sampleName MyApp)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC ON)
set(Boost_COMPILER -gcc49)
SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH} "C:/Program Files/PCL 1.6.0/3rdParty/Boost/include")
SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} "C:/Program Files/PCL 1.6.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib")

find_package(PCL 1.6.0 REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost)
IF (Boost_FOUND)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
    ADD_DEFINITIONS( "-DHAS_BOOST" )
ENDIF()

FIND_PACKAGE(MRPT REQUIRED base;bayes;obs;gui)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories("C:/Program Files/PCL 1.6.0/3rdParty/Boost/include")

link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
link_directories("C:/Program Files/PCL 1.6.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib")

add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable (MyApp Local.cpp part.h grab.h interface.h test.cpp test.h)

target_link_libraries (MyApp ${PCL_LIBRARIES} libeng.lib libmx.lib libmex.lib libmat.lib Aria.lib winmm.lib wsock32.lib)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${sampleName}
${MRPT_LIBS} # This is filled by FIND_PACKAGE(MRPT ...)
"" # Optional extra libs...
)
```

Does anyone know what solves this error?

Comment: Looks like you have Boost installation incompatible with your platform. Check other questions "CMake cannot find Boost" for resolve your problem.

Comment: I checked other questions and tried things mentioned there. but i still get this error. it finds boost include but it doesn't find the libraries. what Boost  installation is compatible with windows 7 64bit for qt?

Comment: As you specifiy `Boost_COMPILER` variable, you need libraries with that suffix (`-gcc49`). It is better to follow @kristian answer, set `Boost_DEBUG` to ON and look (in the output) which **exact libraries** are searched by `find_package(Boost)`.

Comment: As seen in the picture of CMake I put above, it searches for libraries like: "Boost_DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_DEBUG" which has the value: "Boost_DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_DEBUG-NOTFOUND" and other similar lines.      My library files are in the path "C:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\Boost\lib" are like : "boost_date_time-vc100-mt-1_49.lib"

Comment: It should be line started with `Searching for Boost_DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_RELEASE:`, which enumerates **precize** libraries names. The libraries you have intended for *Visual Studio 10.0* (suffix `vc100`). See [official description](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming) about libraries naming.

Comment: there are lines like: "Searching for DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_date_time-mgw48-mt-1_49;" and in the end there is a "Boost_FOUND = 1".     but after that there is line as:  Could not find the following static Boost libraries:
        boost_system
        boost_filesystem
        boost_thread
        boost_date_time
        boost_iostreams
        boost_regex
No Boost libraries were found.
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/PCL 1.6.0/cmake/PCLConfig.cmake:39 (message):
  common is required but boost was not found.

Comment: I think the problem is my library files in boost folder are all "-vc100" while CMake is trying to find "-mgw48" files. Where can I download PCL with -mgw48 libraries? I'm working with "MinGW" not "Visual Studio".

Comment: `Where can I download PCL with -mgw48 libraries?` - By googling something like "PCL MinGW"?

Comment: I googled it a lot and there were no such thing. I wanted PCL to create mgw libraries just like vc100 ones.

Answer (score 1):

So what I did to solve this was first run Cmake as

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(pcd_write)
set(Boost_DEBUG ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC ON)
find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
add_executable (pcd_write pcd_write.cpp)
target_link_libraries (pcd_write ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

And towards the bottom I saw

```
Boost include path: C:/Program Files/PCL 1.6.0/3rdParty/Boost/include
Could not find the following static Boost libraries:
    boost_system
    boost_filesystem
    boost_thread
    boost_date_time
    boost_iostreams
```

I looked in that folder and sure enough I was missing the boost folders for them all.

There might be a better solution, but I just downloaded the latest version of Boost to my computer and replaced the entire `C:/Program Files/PCL 1.6.0/3rdParty/Boost` folder with the new one and everything worked for me

Comment: Can you tell exactly which steps did you do in order to patch the boost library?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can put

```
set(Boost_DEBUG ON)
```

before the command

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost)
```

This gives you some more output and helped me to find the source of other errors.

Next, I would try to set the variables `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` and `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR`, e.g.

```
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "C:/Program Files/PCL 1.6.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib")
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "C:/Program Files/PCL 1.6.0/3rdParty/Boost/include")
```

Comment: I added these lines to the file but it still has the error. Do you happen to have a sample CMakeList.txt file for a project like this? it's my first time using CMake and I don't know how it works exactly.